# How do I change the SD card controller that's used by U-boot for the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+?

Tags: u-boot, device-tree

The Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ has two SD card controllers.

There is custom controller called `sdhost` as shown by [the device tree node](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/arch/arm/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dts#L158):

```
/* SDHOST is used to drive the SD card */
&sdhost {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&sdhost_gpio48>;
    status = "okay";
    bus-width = <4>;
};
```

And an SDHCI-compliant controller as shown by the following [device tree node](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/arch/arm/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dts#L141):

```
/* SDHCI is used to control the SDIO for wireless */
&sdhci {
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_gpio34>;
    status = "okay";
    bus-width = <4>;
    non-removable;
    mmc-pwrseq = <&wifi_pwrseq>;

    brcmf: wifi@1 {
        reg = <1>;
        compatible = "brcm,bcm4329-fmac";
    };
};
```

As referenced by the U-boot comments, U-boot is using `SDHOST` as the SD card controller and `SDHCI` as the WiFi controller.

```
/* SDHOST is used to drive the SD card */
...
/* SDHCI is used to control the SDIO for wireless */
```

**The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to run this [SD card driver](https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/15_writesector/kernel8.img) ([source code here](https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/15_writesector/sd.c)) via U-boot, which uses the Pi's `SDHCI` controller to interact with SD cards.**

The SD card driver runs successfully bare-metal via the Pi's existing bootloader as shown by the output below:

```
EMMC: GPIO set up
EMMC: reset OK
sd_clk divisor 00000068, shift 00000006
EMMC: Sending command 00000000 arg 00000000
EMMC: Sending command 08020000 arg 000001AA
EMMC: Sending command 37000000 arg 00000000
EMMC: Sending command 29020000 arg 51FF8000
EMMC: CMD_SEND_OP_COND returned VOLTAGE CCS 0000000040F98000
...
```

However, when I try to run the binary via U-Boot using the `go` command, the code is stuck during the initialisation phase of the `SDHCI` controller (exact line in source code [here](https://github.com/bztsrc/raspi3-tutorial/blob/master/15_writesector/sd.c#L330)) as shown below:

```
EMMC: GPIO set up
EMMC: reset OK
sd_clk divisor 00000068, shift 00000006
EMMC: Sending command 00000000 arg 00000000
EMMC: Sending command 08020000 arg 000001AA
ERROR: failed to send EMMC command
```

My suspicion is that since U-boot has configured the `SDHCI` controller for Wifi (and not for SD cards), I can no longer use it as an SD card controller. However, I want to use the `SDHCI` controller as the SD Card controller.

What is the best way to get my SD card binary running via U-boot?

Is the only option to configure/recompile U-boot to use the `SDHCI` controller as the main SD card controller (and forget about WiFi)?

If so, some pointers on how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Alternatively, is there a U-boot shell command (like some sort of `reset` command) that give binaries a runtime environment similar to a bare-metal environment that has been un-modified by U-boot?

Edit:

Here is my progress so far. I've figured out how to exclude the custom `SDHOST` driver from being initialised via two methods:

1. Modifying the DTS file by replacing `status = "okay"` with `status = "disabled"` for the custom SDHOST driver.
2. Adding `CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835=n` to U-Boot's `configs/rpi_3_b_plus_defconfig` file.

When I launch U-boot, and run `mmc list`, I see only the SDHCI controller, which is great:

```
U-Boot> mmc list
mmc@7e300000: 0
```

I know the above is the SDHCI controller because its device registers are mapped to the physical address of `7e300000` as shown in `arch/arm/dts/bcm283x.dtsi` below:

```
sdhci: mmc@7e300000 {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-sdhci";
    reg = <0x7e300000 0x100>;
    interrupts = <2 30>;
    clocks = <&clocks BCM2835_CLOCK_EMMC>;
    status = "disabled";
};
```

However, as shown in the following boot logs, U-boot is still not happy to use this controller as the SD card controller:

```
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110
** Bad device specification mmc 0 **
```

Below is the entire boot log:

```
U-Boot 2023.01-00790-g8c80619653-dirty (Feb 11 2023 - 10:04:49 +1100)

DRAM:  948 MiB
RPI 3 Model B+ (0xa020d3)
Core:  63 devices, 14 uclasses, devicetree: embed
MMC:   mmc@7e300000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... Card did not respond to voltage select! : -110
** Bad device specification mmc 0 **
In:    serial
Out:   vidconsole
Err:   vidconsole
Net:   No ethernet found.
starting USB...
Bus usb@7e980000: USB DWC2
scanning bus usb@7e980000 for devices... 4 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
U-Boot> mmc list
mmc@7e300000: 0
```

My suspicion is that the SDHCI controller is still being treated by U-Boot as a WiFi controller (I can't tell for sure). What are some troubleshooting steps I can take to figure out what is going on?

Comment: "*What is the best way to get my SD card binary running via U-boot?*" -- Try modifying the U-Boot Device Tree by paring it down to a minimal set of only-essential devices. Try *not* initializing both SD controllers by replacing `status = "okay";` with `status = "disabled";`.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the pointer. Once I figure out the exact modifications I need to make to U-Boot's Device Tree (by directly editing the DT), is it the same idea if I just create an overlay and apply it as explained by this part of U-Boot's [docs](https://u-boot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/fdt_overlays.html)?

Comment: For a quick experiment, I wouldn't get fancy. I would simply modify the **.dts** file. In fact, all you have to do comment out the `status = "okay";` property statement (assuming that the prior assignment was a "disable"). But if there is no status property at all/anywhere, then the node status defaults to "okay", i.e. enabled.

Comment: @sawdust Yep that makes sense. So I've been experimented with modifying the DTS file as you've described and I've also found another way to prevent the custom SDHOST driver from being loaded by adding `CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835=n` to the `configs/rpi_3_b_plus_defconfig` file. When I run `mmc list` in U-Boot, I see only `mmc@7e300000: 0`, which is the SDHCI controller I want. However, U-boot still isn't using the SDHCI controller as the SD Card controller. I've updated my question with more details about this. Do you have any ideas on how to force U-boot to use the SDHCI controller?

Comment: "*I've also found another way to prevent the custom SDHOST driver from being loaded ...*" -- You mean "initialized"? U-Boot is not capable of any driver "loading". Your hack (using incorrect syntax) completely removes the driver from the build and U-Boot executable; any reference in the DT is thus ignored. Do not conflate "*loading*" with "*initializing*"; they are distinct operations.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for highlighting - I've amended my terminology accordingly.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on the raspberry pi stack exchange

Comment: "*Here is my progress so far. I've figured out how to exclude the custom SDHOST driver from being initialised*" -- My assumption is that you also need to disable the `&sdhci` node, since that is the device that your standalone is trying to use. IOW you have not accurately followed the advice previously given.

Comment: @Rob -- This question qualifies as "*a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*"

Comment: @sawdust In that case I vote to close as he has not tagged the question with the programming language he is using or supplied a [mcve] of his code. Hover over the raspberry tag and read that popup

Comment: @sawdust I believe you posted an earlier comment that has since been deleted, which greatly helped me achieve what I wanted in U-boot. I've posted my solution based on that conment, which achieves my desired outcome. Admittedly, the solution doesn't explain precisely why this change works (because I'm still a little hazy on the exact details) so I would greatly welcome any edits you may have for my posted solution. Alternatively, I'm also happy for you to post your own solution/explanation and I will accept it as the answer (if you wish to do that). Thank so much for all the help.

Comment: I'm having same problem and I don't even use U-Boot, qemu-system-aarch64 -serial mon:stdio -machine raspi3b -m 1G -smp 4 -kernel kernel8.img -d int

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to change the following line in the `sdhci` [node of the DT](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/arch/arm/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dts#L141) located at `arch/arm/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dts` from

```c
pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_gpio34>;
```

to

```c
pinctrl-0 = <&sdhost_gpio48>;
```

Then I recompile U-boot and use the resultant U-boot binary as the Pi’s bootloader.

The final and desired result is that:

1. U-boot can still use the `sdhost` driver and controller to access the SD card when it is running (which is U-boot’s default preference).
2. The binary run by U-boot (via the `go` command) can also manipulate the `sdhci` controller’s device registers to interact with the SD card.

For additional context around the solution, the `sdhost_gpio48` reference above is located in [this DTSI file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/latest/source/arch/arm/dts/bcm283x.dtsi#L222) located at `arch/arm/dts/bcm283x.dtsi`:

```c
sdhost_gpio48: sdhost_gpio48 {
    brcm,pins = <48 49 50 51 52 53>;
    brcm,function = <BCM2835_FSEL_ALT0>;
};
```

The `pinctrl-0` parameter we have changed refers to “Pin Control” and detailed documentation about this parameter can be found [here](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/pin-control.html?highlight=pinctrl#pinctrl-pin-control-subsystem).

From my understanding, our change specifies the same GPIO pins that are being used for the SDHOST controller for the SDHCI controller, which enables us to use the SDHCI controller as an SD card controller when the binary is running.